# Replace Values in Spark Dataframe based on Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset of integers, some of which are real data and some of which, above a certain threshold, are error codes. I also have a Map of column names to the beginning of their error code range. I would like to use this map to conditionally replace values, for example None if the value of the row in each column is above the start of the error range.

```
val errors = Map("Col_1" -> 100, "Col_2" -> 10)

val df = Seq(("john", 1, 100), ("jacob", 10, 100), ("heimer", 1000, 
1)).toDF("name", "Col_1", "Col_2")

df.take(3)
// name   | Col_1 | Col_2
// john   | 1     | 1
// jacob  | 10    | 10
// heimer | 1000  | 1

//create some function like this
def fixer = udf((column_value, column_name) => {
    val crit_val = errors(column_name)
    if(column_value >= crit_val) {
        None
    } else {
        column_value
    }
}

//apply it in some way
val fixed_df = df.columns.map(_ -> fixer(_))

//to get output like this:
fixed_df.take(3)
// name   | Col_1 | Col_2
// john   | 1     | 1
// jacob  | 10    | None
// heimer | None  | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too convenient to do this using a UDF - a UDF expects a specific column (or more than one) and returns a single column, and here you want to handle various different columns. Moreover, the act of checking a threshold and replacing the value with some constant can be performed using Spark's built-in method `when` and does not require a UDF.

So, here's a way to use `when` for each column that has some threshold, thus iteratively going through the relevant columns and producing the desired DataFrame (we'll replace "bad" values with `null`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// fold the list of errors, replacing the original column
// with a "corrected" column with same name in each iteration
val newDf = errors.foldLeft(df) { case (tmpDF, (colName, threshold)) =>
  tmpDF.withColumn(colName, when($"$colName" > threshold, null).otherwise($"$colName"))
}

newDf.show()
// +------+-----+-----+
// |  name|Col_1|Col_2|
// +------+-----+-----+
// |  john|    1|    1|
// | jacob|   10| null|
// |heimer| null|    1|
// +------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you @tzach-zohar! This was perfect.